# How can factoring costly code out into a seperate function improve efficiency?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, refactoring, compiler-optimization

In our code, I am pulling out a computationally expensive function(in VC++ 13) into a separate function and it works 10% faster! I didn't understand how that works. I expect that pulling it out to a separate function should be more expensive since it has the overhead of creating a new stack frame and cleaning it out. But that is not the case. How does that happen? Also, another bit of information is that the function is called in a loop.

Comment: Did you inspect the generated assembler code? Even if you are not familiar with assembler (as am I), it is often possible to see the cause of the effect easily.

Comment: It would also help to reproduce the effect with a small example that you can post. You can also inspect the assembler code of this example with https://godbolt.org/.

Comment: @Jens I would not be able to post an example of it since I am not sure I can reproduce it with a new piece of code. Also, all I did was move out the few lines from the original function to a new function and replaced the lines in the original place by a call to the new function.

Comment: I am afraid that this will reduce the chances of an useful answer. If the function is called in a loop and it is defined in the same compilation unit it will probably be inlined anyways and there is no difference to the original code. Again, the assembler code will tell you. A 10% difference is also not that much, and dependening on the way you measure may be well in the error margin of your benchmark.

Comment: The only time's I've noticed performance improvement due to moving a portion into a separate function has been due to the optimizer better able to utilize the registers, even though the function is inlined.  And that would be due to reusing variables (which extends their "lifespan"; but that was before SSA optimization) instead of declaring and using them at their appropriate scope.

Comment: Is the expensive code perhaps called conditionally? A similar optimization I have seen applied to good effect was making sure that the common case was fast and uncommon cases are in a separate function. This made sure that the common code was closer together improving cache locality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's of course quite difficult to guess what the cause is, with both your code missing and MSVC's code being closed, but two possibilities could be:

- When you pulled the code out into a separate function, you made certain guarantees which were not obvious in the larger function (e.g. with `const` and `__restrict__` perhaps), allowing certain optimizations to kick in.
- An opportunity to apply an optimization is missed by the compiler - due to some oversight-type bug - but is picked up when the code is in its own function.